# Como retornar quantos elementos de um array não tiveram sua posição alterada

Tags: javascript, array

Dado um array de números, que deve ser ordenado em ordem decrescente; eu fiz da seguinte maneira:

```js
const clientes = [40, 36, 50, 21, 17];

console.log(clientes.sort(function(a, b){return b - a})); // [ 50, 40, 36, 21, 17 ]
```

Eu preciso retornar quantos números não mudaram de posição dentro do array, neste caso 2, alguém sabe resolver ? Procurei algum método para isso não encontrei, não sei se tem que combinar mais de um método, usar estrutura condicional.

O exercicio começa com o seguinte código e eu preciso completar:

```js
// a função gets é implementada dentro do sistema para ler as entradas(inputs) dos dados
let N = gets();
let clientes = [];

//implemente aqui o seu código
  
};
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Você conhece a estrutura [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), que pode ser usada para percorrer uma lista de itens?

Comment: Você teria que varrer os itens do array sequencialmente e comparar o item em uma determinada posição do array original com os itens da mesma posição no array ordenado. Se um determinado par estiver diferente, é porque ele está em outra posição.

Comment: @Benilson conheço o básico, mas não sei comparar se os elementos do array filtrado, se encontram no mesmo índice do array original, e por fim retornar um único valor que é quantos elementos se encontram no mesmo índice, que no array que utilizei de exemplo é 2.

Comment: @Jefferson ok, vou postar uma resposta com um código de exemplo usando o for para comparar os arrays.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a estrutura [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), para percorrer os itens de um array e comparar com os itens de outro array no mesmo índice.

É o que a resposta do @Haroldo_OK diz, só que adicionei um código de exemplo.

```js
const clientes = [40, 36, 50, 21, 17];
const quantidadeClientes = clientes.length;
const indicesMesmaPosicao = [];
let indice; 
const clientesOrdenados = [];

// clientesOrdenados não pode receber clientes.sort, pois iria armazenar uma referência a clientes e não uma nova lista
for (indice = 0; indice < quantidadeClientes; indice++) {
    clientesOrdenados.push(clientes[indice]);
}

// ordena a nova lista
clientesOrdenados.sort(
    function(a, b) { 
        return (b - a);
    }
);

for (indice = 0; indice < quantidadeClientes; indice++) {
   // compara os itens no mesmo índice
   if (clientes[indice] === clientesOrdenados[indice]) {
       indicesMesmaPosicao.push(indice);
   }
}

console.log(indicesMesmaPosicao);
console.log(indicesMesmaPosicao.length);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era o que eu queria e me ajudou a entender a lógica. Enquanto eu tentava resolver eu percebi que não poderia usar o sort direto, pois alterava o primeiro array. Como eu não sabia usar o push desse jeito, acabei chegando nesta solução que talvez não seja a ideal mas também funciona:
`const clientesTemporario = clientes.map(repete)

function repete(num) { return num; }

clientesOrdenados = clientesTemporario.sort( function(a, b){return (b - a); });`

Comment: @Jefferson Sim, o map retorna um novo array, parabéns por lembrar dele, melhor que usar o for para criar o array que será ordenado e usado na comparação.

Comment: @Jefferson Vc também pode fazer `clientes.slice()` pra criar uma cópia do array - é mais direto que `map`, por não precisar de uma função de *callback*

Comment: @hkotsubo de fato, obrigado, `const clientesOrdenados = clientes.slice();`

Comment: @hkotsubo tinha uma resposta que foi apagada, onde o rapaz usava o [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). :o)

Comment: @Benilson Sim, também é outra opção :-)